# Database Error - no such column

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

I have a project, with an app, article. And there I have a page to list all the articles, and another to display the selected article and its comments. Everything was fine before I used migration from south, and made some changes, i.e., before in the Comment model i had a field for

> name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

and changed it to:

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
second_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now when i load my articles.html page, everthings ok, but when i load article.html, i get an error:

> DatabaseError at /articles/get/1/
>
> no such column: article_comment.first_name
>
> Error during template rendering
>
> In template C:\Users\Robin\web\django_test\article\templates\article.html, error at line 21

In in line 21 article.html:
`{% if article.comment_set.all %}`

I think the problem is with `comment_set.all`. Even in the console it gives me the same error as the above. So, how do i get all the comments from the given aritcle? Or did I made some mistake in the code? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from time import time

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

views.py:

```
def article(request, article_id=1):
    return render_to_response('article.html',
        {'article': Article.objects.get(id=article_id) })
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('first_name','second_name', 'body')
```

article.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="/articles/all">Articles</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}

<h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
<p>{{article.body}}</p>
{% if article.thumbnail %}
<p><img src="/static/assets/{{ article.thumbnail }}" width="200"/></p>
{% endif %}
<p>{{ article.likes }} people liked this article.</p>
<p><a href="/articles/like/{{ article.id }}">Like</a></p>

<h2>Comments</h2>

{% if article.comment_set.all %}

{% for c in article.comment_set.all %}
<p>{{ c.name }}: {{ c.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
<p>No comment</p>

{% endif %}
<p><a href="/articles/add_comment/{{ article.id }}">Add comment</a></p>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `Everything was fine before I used migration from south, and made some changes` - Can you elaborate on this ? Do you have a migrations directory in the app with some files in it ?

Comment: Yes. I have a migration folder in my app folder. Should i post it?

Comment: No need to post it.. So, once you did a `schemamigration`, did you do a `./manage.py migrate <app_name>` ?

Comment: Yes. I did `python manage.py migrate app`. And it did deleted the name field and changed it to first_name and second_name fields.

Comment: looks like it did not take the changes then. [Check this](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/ConvertingAnApp)

Comment: Ok... i didn't
`python manage.py migrate article --fake` and did `manage.py migrate article`. But it did created migrations. What do I do to make it right now? Will i have to delete my database and create again?